# Data frame R - lookup for the part of the string and return certain two values

Tags: r, regex, string

I have got a data frame with xml export and I want to look up for the ceratin string and return two values from it. Below is the code for the sample of my data.

```
a <- c(
  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><businessObjectChanges version="1"><table><datetime>1500977276442</datetime><name>XX_header</name><row><datetime>1500977276442</datetime><transactionType>UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>est_groundtime</name><newValue>420</newValue><oldValue>480</oldValue><mimeType>TIME</mimeType></column><column><name>start_time</name><newValue>540</newValue><oldValue>480</oldValue><mimeType>TIME</mimeType></column><column><name>XXno_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>11</newValue><oldValue>11</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>',
   '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><businessObjectChanges version="1"><table><datetime>1500977363880</datetime><name>XX_header</name><row><datetime>1500977363880</datetime><transactionType>UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>end_time</name><newValue>922</newValue><oldValue>960</oldValue><mimeType>TIME</mimeType></column><column><name>XXno_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>11</newValue><oldValue>11</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>',
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><businessObjectChanges version="1"><table><datetime>1500977598476</datetime><name>XX_header</name><row><datetime>1500977598476</datetime><transactionType>UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>act_start_date</name><newValue>16642</newValue><oldValue>null</oldValue><mimeType>DATE</mimeType></column><column><name>act_start_time</name><newValue>607</newValue><oldValue>0</oldValue><mimeType>TIME</mimeType></column><column><name>act_end_date</name><newValue>16642</newValue><oldValue>null</oldValue><mimeType>DATE</mimeType></column><column><name>act_end_time</name><newValue>667</newValue><oldValue>0</oldValue><mimeType>TIME</mimeType></column><column><name>delay</name><newValue>7</newValue><oldValue>0</oldValue><mimeType>TIME</mimeType></column><column><name>XXno_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>205</newValue><oldValue>205</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>',
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><businessObjectChanges version="1"><table><datetime>1500977613945</datetime><name>XX_header</name><row><datetime>1500977613945</datetime><transactionType>UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>XX_status</name><newValue>-2</newValue><oldValue>18</oldValue><mimeType>INT</mimeType></column><column><name>XXno_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>205</newValue><oldValue>205</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>',
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><businessObjectChanges version="1"><table><datetime>1500977892448</datetime><name>XX_header</name><row><datetime>1500977892448</datetime><transactionType>UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>XX_status</name><newValue>19</newValue><oldValue>-2</oldValue><mimeType>INT</mimeType></column><column><name>XXno_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>29</newValue><oldValue>29</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>',
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><businessObjectChanges version="1"><table><datetime>1500977738390</datetime><name>XX_header</name><row><datetime>1500977738390</datetime><transactionType>UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>act_start_date</name><newValue>16641</newValue><oldValue>null</oldValue><mimeType>DATE</mimeType></column><column><name>act_start_time</name><newValue>367</newValue><oldValue>0</oldValue><mimeType>TIME</mimeType></column><column><name>act_end_date</name><newValue>16641</newValue><oldValue>null</oldValue><mimeType>DATE</mimeType></column><column><name>act_end_time</name><newValue>667</newValue><oldValue>0</oldValue><mimeType>TIME</mimeType></column><column><name>XXno_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>44</newValue><oldValue>44</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>',
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><businessObjectChanges version="1"><table><datetime>1500977757374</datetime><name>XX_header</name><row><datetime>1500977757374</datetime><transactionType>UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>XX_status</name><newValue>19</newValue><oldValue>18</oldValue><mimeType>INT</mimeType></column><column><name>XXno_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>44</newValue><oldValue>44</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>',
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><businessObjectChanges version="1"><table><datetime>1500977836229</datetime><name>XX_header</name><row><datetime>1500977836229</datetime><transactionType>UPDATE</transactionType><column><name>act_start_date</name><newValue>16640</newValue><oldValue>null</oldValue><mimeType>DATE</mimeType></column><column><name>act_start_time</name><newValue>96</newValue><oldValue>0</oldValue><mimeType>TIME</mimeType></column><column><name>act_end_date</name><newValue>16640</newValue><oldValue>null</oldValue><mimeType>DATE</mimeType></column><column><name>act_end_time</name><newValue>156</newValue><oldValue>0</oldValue><mimeType>TIME</mimeType></column><column><name>XXno_i</name><primaryKey>true</primaryKey><newValue>203</newValue><oldValue>203</oldValue></column></row></table></businessObjectChanges>'

)

a <- as.data.frame(a)
```

What I need for my data frame 'a' is two columns. First, one with is based on  following XX_status and the second one is  following again XX_status.

So, lines 1 to 3 do not contain XX_status so anything for them, line 4 has it with the below extract and it would be -2 and 18 and for line 5 it would be 18 and 2 etc...

Any ideas will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `stringr` package and REGEX to extract these values, as shown below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

a <- c(...) # your XML string here

a <- as.data.frame(a)

a <-  a 
%>% mutate(
status = str_extract(a, "XX_status[\\<\\/.\\>\\w\\d\\-]+\\<\\/oldValue\\>\\ 
<mimeType\\>"),
newValue = str_extract(status, "newValue\\>[\\-]*\\d+"),
newValue = as.numeric(str_extract(newValue, "[\\-]*\\d+")),
oldValue = str_extract(status, "oldValue\\>[\\-]*\\d+"),
oldValue = as.numeric(str_extract(oldValue, "[\\-]*\\d+"))) 
%>% select(-status)
```

Comment: Ok. I need to make some changes. It is a great code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to handle this case. I tried to extract a specific part of the long strings first using `stri_extract_all_regex()`. Then, I further tried to extract numbers in the second `stri_extract_all_regex()`. I then created two columns using `unnest_wider()` and assigned columns names to the data frame in the end. I hope this will help you.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

transmute(a,
          res = stri_extract_all_regex(str = a,
                                       pattern = "XX_status</name><newValue>-?\\d+</newValue><oldValue>-?\\d+</oldValue>") %>% 
                stri_extract_all_regex(pattern = "(?<=>)-?\\d+(?=<)")) %>% 
unnest_wider(res) %>% 
setNames(nm = c("new_value", "old_value"))

#  new_value old_value
#  <chr>     <chr>    
#1 NA        NA       
#2 NA        NA       
#3 NA        NA       
#4 -2        18       
#5 19        -2       
#6 NA        NA       
#7 19        18       
#8 NA        NA
```

Comment: Just one question - when I try to get results as a new df it prints all the lines with the following text: 'New names:
* `` -> ...1'  Any idea how to do it without being printed or how to add "new_valuue" and "old_value" as columns to a?

Comment: @Kalenji When you texted me, I was asleep. You probably have multiple columns, right? In that case, you wanna do something like this: `paste(rep(c("new_value", "old_value"), times = 2), rep(1:2, each = 2), sep = "_")`. You wanna have this in `setNames()`. `times` in the first `rep()` indicates how many pairs you have. In the second `rep()`, change `1:2` to `1:n`. n is equal to the number in `times`. In this way, you can create all column names you need.